# Is it possible to add recurring shipping fee in Stripe Subscriptions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am a newbie to Stripe subscriptions and learning about the plans and invoice line items.

Is it possible to add recurring shipping fees in Stripe Subscriptions or should I include the shipping fee as a part of the subscription price?

Also, I am trying to add one-time setup fee via invoice line item but the charge is not getting included. 
I am using Rails and this is how I am proceeding.
1)Creating a customer
2)Adding the subscription plan to that customer 
3)Then creating the invoice line item for one time set up fee.

I am not receiving any error during the testing, but the one-time fee is not getting included in the payment.

Help would be appreciated.

TIA

Sri

Comment: Please include some of the relevant code to help debug it..

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create the invoice item *before* creating the subscription, please see:

https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices#adding-invoice-items

Any uninvoiced invoice items will be included on the subscription's first invoice, and this is the recommended way to do one-time charges. You'll want your code to do this:

1. Create the customer (don't pass plan)
2. Create the invoice item
3. Create the subscription.

Hope that clears things up!